# How do I use a font with a space in its name in gVim?

Tags: windows, fonts, gvim

I just installed vim-airline, and I want to use a font that has support for the cool arrow glyphs that vim-airline supports. So, I downloaded the font "Liberation Mono for Powerline" from the [Powerline fonts repository](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts). I installed the font by double clicking on the `.ttf` file and selecting "Install font" from the dialog that popped up. I can see the font in the Control Panel Fonts folder.

However, when I try to load the font in vim by doing

```
set guifont="Liberation Mono for Powerline:h11:cANSI"
```

the `guifont` string becomes blank, and the font falls back to Fixedsys Regular. So how do I use this cool new monospaced font that I've downloaded?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't quote the argument to a `:set` command using double-quotes because in the context of a `:set` command, a double-quote begins a comment. There are at least two ways to do this.

1. Quote spaces with backslashes.

   `set guifont=Liberation\ Mono\ for\ Powerline:h11:cANSI`
2. Use `:let` insetead of `:set`.

   `let &guifont = "Liberation Mono for Powerline:h11:cANSI"`

See

```
:help option-backslash
:help let-option
```